# In a web application, current session is null when "ressource cannot be found" exception occurs

Tags: c#, asp.net, web

In my ASP.NET application, i have a procedure that log all exceptions to a file (using `Application_Error()` and `global.asax`). Inside that procedure, I log several things like current datetime, user name and such.

It works well, however, if someone (that is already logged) try to access a page that doesn't exists (eg : http://www.mywebsite.com/foo.aspx) current user name information cannot be accessed from procedure, because `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session` is null. At first, i was thinking that session has been lost. it is not true, because if i press back i can still use the website (links still works without being redirected to login page).

**What is the reason of session being null if a ressource is not found ?** is it because session object is only initialized by asp after he know which page to deliver ? or maybe something is not configurated correctly on my website ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the ASP.NET event lifecycle:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb470252.aspx

In particular, how `HttpApplication` processes your request. Note, that before `BeginRequest` (no.3) and `AcquireRequestState` (no.12) there are at least few important events.

Now then, your session is available only **after** `AcquireRequestState`. If you have **any** error in one of prior events, you'll get the null reference on `Session`.

"Resource not found" is just one example but in general you have to be prepared that `Session` is just not available in early events of the processing pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

If your application is throwing something like HTTP 404 (File Not Found) error, the Session is always null. Reason being the HttpContext object is created by ASP.NET during the page request. Since no page was found, no HttpContext Object can be created; therefore, no Session can exist when a 404 error occurs.

Checkout the following  asp.net thread for similar issue and solution

http://forums.asp.net/t/1648782.aspx/1

Answer (score 0):

The `Session` belongs to `HttpContext` and `HttpContext` is not created if there is no page.

You might need to create a custom 404 page and log there if having session id for all your log entries is mandatory.